# Bitbucket server, block merges to master in case there is a running build

Tags: groovy, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I am trying ot disable the merge button on bitbucket-servcer when there is a running build on master. I wasn't able to find a pre hook that would do that for me so I resolved to doing it with ScriptRunner

My scripts looks like this

```
import com.atlassian.bitbucket.repository.Repository
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.customisers.WithPlugin
@WithPlugin("com.atlassian.bitbucket.server.bitbucket-build")
import com.atlassian.bitbucket.build.status.BuildStatusRepositorySearchRequest
import com.atlassian.bitbucket.build.status.RepositoryBuildStatusService
import com.atlassian.bitbucket.repository.RepositoryService
import com.atlassian.sal.api.component.ComponentLocator
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.customisers.PluginModule
import com.atlassian.bitbucket.util.PageRequestImpl

def repService = ComponentLocator.getComponent(RepositoryService)

def repo = repService.getBySlug('PROJECT_ID', 'REPO_ID')

@PluginModule
RepositoryBuildStatusService repositoryBuildStatusService

def builds = repositoryBuildStatusService.search(
    new BuildStatusRepositorySearchRequest.Builder(repo).build(),
    new PageRequestImpl(0, 100)
).values

     builds.each { build -> 
            log.warn "build="
        }

def destinationBranchIsDefault = mergeRequest.pullRequest.toRef.displayId == defaultBranch


destinationBranchIsDefault
```

However I am getting errors like

```
Script113.groovy: 13: [Static type checking] - You tried to call a method which is not allowed: com.atlassian.bitbucket.repository.RepositoryService#getBySlug(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
 @ line 13, column 12.
   def repo = repService.getBySlug('PROJECT_ID', 'REPO_ID')
```

I should have permissions on the repo, I might be missing something?